# Longitudinal EM Waves in Vacuum

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

As far as I know longitudinal electromagnetic waves are possible in plasmas. I stumbled upon the notion that the QED vacuum is "made out of" virtual electron-positron pairs and effects like Vacuum-Polarization are possible just like in a medium. Why then are longitudinal electromagnetic waves in the vacuum not possible?

Comment: Why do you think longitudinal electromagnetic waves aren't possible in a vacuum?

Comment: an empty waveguide has EM waves with longitudinal components

Comment: Am I wrong? I thought longitudinal electromagnetic waves are not possible in vacuum. Isn't this related to the fact that there is no ether?